# EJS navbar template, set navbar class="active" based upon url

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, ejs

i have a global ejs navbar template with some basic styling:

```
   <ul>
     <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
     <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
     <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
   </ul>
```

i include this in every disired page with:

```
<% include templates/navbar.ejs%>
```

now my problem is that when you are on a different page than the home page the active navbar button does not correspond with the page title, like when you are on about page the active part of the navbar still is the home page. Is there any way to change the active part of the navbar corresponding to the page the user is currently on?

Greetings Ruben

Comment: What I did was, pass an object with the active url (route) and then, added some test to add the .active class

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18501402/finding-current-url-inside-ejs-view-when-using-express

Comment: Yeah that helps, it is working now