# Can I use a conditional statement in my EJS doc for a directory path in my Node/Express app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

New to EJS. I want to make a conditional statement basically saying if I am on this directory path, then replace this link in my nav bar.

```
 <%let url = window.document.URL;
            if(!url.includes('prospects/index')) {%>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="/prospects">Targeted Prospects</a>
</li>
<% } else { %>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="/prospects/new">Add Prospects</a>
</li>
<% } %>
```

My res.render

```
module.exports.index = async (req, res) => {
const prospects = await Prospect.find({});
res.render('prospects/index', { prospects })
};
```

I was hoping to see when I'm on my route "prospects/index" I'll see "Add Prospects" and all other routes I'll see "Targeted Prospects." Is there a way to target that route in my if statement? Thanks!

Comment: You need to test `window.location`. `if (!window.location.includes('prospects/index')`

Comment: Getting window is undefined. Not sure where I'm supposed to define it.

Comment: `window` is a standard object in the browser.

Comment: I guess you can use `req.originalUrl`  if(req.originalUrl === '/prospects/index')

Comment: EJS is just a template engine. What else are you using that would know what path you’re on, and how is it being used together with EJS? Is this server-side Node, Express.js?

Comment: Yes, it's still server-side Node, Express

Comment: What does your `res.render` call look like? Please [edit] the relevant code into your question.

Comment: Added my res.render to my original post from my controllers.

Comment: The `window` API is only available client side. If you want to get the URL server side then you need to use a server-side API (i.e. use the `req` object).

Comment: @Quentin That may or may not be useful reading, but it’s definitely not a duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18501402/finding-current-url-inside-ejs-view-when-using-express

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the decision based on something accessible to the template. The values you can use in the template come from the object you pass to `res.render`. So that could be [the request’s path](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.path), like you came up with:

```js
res.render('prospects/index', {
    prospects,
    requestPath: req.path,
});
```

```js
<% if (!requestPath.startsWith('/prospects/index')) %>
```

But I would prefer to let the router handle the request paths:

```js
res.render('prospects/index', {
    prospects,
    isIndex: true,  // you might want to come up with a more descriptive name
})
```

```js
<% if (!isIndex) %>
```

Then any non-index paths that render the same template should pass `isIndex: false`.